# merge two query arguments into one WP_Query call

Tags: wp-query, query, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm overriding WooCommerce's default search query to include searching by SKU as well.

```php
// default search query
$query_default_search = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "post_type" => "product",
        "s" => $search_query
    )
);

// SKU query
$query_search_by_sku = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "post_type" => "product",
        "meta_query" => array(
            array(
                "key" => "_sku",
                "value" => $search_query,
                "compare" => "LIKE"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

If the default search query doesn't return any posts, I assume that an SKU has been entered and I run the SKU query. However, I want to merge both query arguments into one `WP_Query` call, rather than merging the results of both queries using `array_merge`.
If both queries had meta-query, I could use an OR relation, but this is different.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
$query_withMeta_search = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "post_type" => "product",
        "s" => $search_query,
        "meta_query" => array(
                "key" => "_sku",
                "value" => $search_query,
                "compare" => "LIKE"
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it does work. The only problem is that it returns products that have search query in title AND in SKU. And most probably you wanted to get OR instead of AND ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create the array you'd like to use in it's entirety before running. Something like

```
if($search_query) {
     // create the basic query array
} else {
     // create the more advanced query array
}

// then run the query on the one you want
new WP_Query($args);
```

Hope that helps.